# Not able to retrieve the gmail contact photo

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api

I am creating Google integrated asp.net Application. i want to retrieve all the information

of a friend of logged in user in gmail. I got the list of contacts in gridview. But I am

not able to get the profile pic of any contact. I am adding datacolumns dynamically in the

gridview.

Here is my code of retrieving photo:

```
 RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings(App_Name, Uname, Password_property);

        rs.AutoPaging = true;

        ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);

        Feed<Contact> f = cr.GetContacts();

        foreach (Contact t in f.Entries)
        {
            Stream photo = cr.Service.Query(t.PhotoUri);

                if (photo != null)
                {
                    dr1["Profile Pic"] = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(photo);
                }
         }
```

It crashes and says remote server returned an error.

Then i tried another code:

```
Stream photo = cr.GetPhoto(t);

if (photo != null)
{
    dr1["Profile Pic"] = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(photo);
}
```

It also crashes and gives error of

```
Google.GData.Client.GDataNotModifiedException : Content not modified
```

I am not able to get the contact photo anyhow.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I am still not able to get images. Can anyone please provide some code. I need it urgently

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine for me:

```
public static List<ContactDetail> GetAllContact(string username, string password)
{
    List<ContactDetail> contactDetails = new List<ContactDetail>();
    ContactsQuery query = new ContactsQuery(ContactsQuery.CreateContactsUri("default"));
    RequestSettings rs = new RequestSettings("W7CallerID", username, password);
    ContactsRequest cr = new ContactsRequest(rs);

    Feed<Contact> feed = cr.GetContacts();
    foreach (Contact entry in feed.Entries)
    {
        ContactDetail contact = new ContactDetail
        {
            Name = entry.Name.FullName,
            EmailAddress1 = entry.Emails.Count >= 1 ? entry.Emails[0].Address : "",
            EmailAddress2 = entry.Emails.Count >= 2 ? entry.Emails[1].Address : "",
            Phone = entry.Phonenumbers.Count >= 1 ? entry.Phonenumbers[0].Value : "",
            Details = entry.Content,
            Pic = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(cr.Service.Query(entry.PhotoUri))
        };

        contactDetails.Add(contact);
    }

    return contactDetails;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have managed to successfully retrieve photographs using the GData Library. Photographs are returned as a stream.

The following code retrieves the stream

```
                requestFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("c1", ApplicationName, parameters);
            service = new ContactsService(ApplicationName);
            service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;

            resultsStream = service.Query(new Uri(Uri));
```